# Is Intl.NumberFormat formatting correct for Poland?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, number-formatting, ecma

I have noticed that the formating of several countries (Poland, Russia, France and more) follows a strange behaviour. The format starts to apply on values with more that 4 digits. You can see it in the code below.

Unfortunately I haven't found any international standards for that and I have seen that in other programing languages the format for this countries starts from the 4th digit.

I am wondering if the Intl.NumberFormat follows the correct formatting standards.

```js
const simpleFormat = new Intl.NumberFormat('pl-PL', {
  style: 'decimal'});
let short = simpleFormat.format(1234);
let long = simpleFormat.format(12345);

console.log(short);
console.log(long);
```

Expected output:

1 234

12 345

Comment: According to [ECMA 402](https://tc39.es/ecma402/#annex-implementation-dependent-behaviour), "Localized decimal and grouping separators" are implementation-dependent. I'm seeing what you're seeing on Firefox 85.0, Arch Linux: `1234` and `12 345`.

Comment: As a datapoint, Estonian uses similar logic where you don't insert a space for 4-digit numbers (`1234`), but you do for 5-digit ones (`12 345`). While I haven't traced down the official spec here, I wouldn't find it surprising if Polish did something similar.

Answer (score 2):

in case anyone is still looking for it - Intl.NumberFormat has an option `useGrouping` and if it is set to `true` for `pl` then space separator is also inserted in the 4-digit number

Comment: Unfortunately this won't do. I tried: `new Intl.NumberFormat('pl-PL').format(1000, { useGrouping:true });` with no success

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
(1000).toLocaleString('pl-PL', {useGrouping: true})
// result: '1 000'
```

You can add:

```
(1000).toLocaleString('pl-PL', {useGrouping:true, minimumFractionDigits:2, maximumFractionDigits:2})
// result: '1 000,00'
```