# Why JavaScript omits thousand separator for four digit values?

Tags: javascript

JavaScript erroneously omits thousand separator (space) for PL locales for values of four digit.

code samples :

```
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('pl-PL').format(1000));  // returns 1000, expecting 1 000 
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('pl-PL').format(10000)); // returns 10 000 (that's ok)
```

Is the implementation spoiled?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66103296/is-intl-numberformat-formatting-correct-for-poland

Comment: No. Your expectation is wrong. Thousands separators are only used for more than 4 digits.

Comment: @Bergi: Funny if you do `new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US').format(1000);` it returns "1,000". So the separator placement depends on your locale.

Comment: @KoalaYeung I think that was his point

Comment: @KoalaYeung Well American English is weird… But see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Exceptions_to_digit_grouping and https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separator_dziesi%C4%99tny.